# How to play 'tap' sound on button 'Touch Up Inside' action in Cocoa?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa

I have an IBAction in my viewController and i want to play the iPhone tap sound on every call os this IBAction.

Is there any way to do this with sysyem sound or do i have to put an MP3 inside the app?

What's the best way to do this on code?

Answer (score 3):

You will need to provide your own audio file and use iOS [System Sound Services](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/SystemSoundServicesReference/Reference/reference.html).